# can not access route on nginx using express

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx

i created a Site using React js and i made some changes to Nginx to rewrite route to file so i wont get 404 error , recently i tried to use express on  , if i config nginx for single page app buy using :
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; }
i ll get notFound page from my app when i'm trying to reach /api , if i don't config it i can access to my express server but Site shows notFound by nginx  when i try to access url except homepage Directly ,

so im looking for some exception config for nginx ,
i want to rewrite all route to index html except any url start with /api/*

Please save my Life :) i can not find solution on internet 
Kind Regards

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow :) It seems your question is not very detailled and therefore it is not easy to help. You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and ask your question in a way that will be clear for the people that can help you!

Answer (score 5):

While it is not clear what kind of architecture you have, I will make an assumption that React app is running on a certain port, e.g. 3000 and backend server `/api` on port 5000.

Here is a very basic example of a nginx configuration that routes all `/api` requests to the server (port 5000) and the rest - to the React app.

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
    server api:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        // try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; // to redirect to the index page
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }    
}
```